# Repeating numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, count, conditional-statements

I've been stuck with this for some time. I'm supposed to create a method, that counts how many of the numbers appear to be the same. As an example, 7-2-2-7 is supposed to be give 2, and 4-4-5-5 is supposed to give 2, while 1-2-3-4 gives 0. But my program gives me 3 when there are only 2 different numbers that are identical??? Help?

```
public class Help {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          numRepeat(7, 2, 2, 7);
       }//main
       public static void numbers(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
          int rep = 0;
          int sum = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                if (a == b || b == c || c == d) {
                   rep++;
                   sum += rep;
                } else if (b == a || b == c || b == d) {
                   rep++;
                   sum += rep;
                } else if (c == a || c == b || c == d) {
                   rep++;
                   sum += rep;
                } else { /**do nothing**/ }
             }//for loop
          System.out.println("The sum of repeated digits is " + sum);
       }//numRepeat
    }//class
```

Comment: Why do you need the `for` loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't `7-2-2-2` and `4-4-5-5` both be 2?  You've got two numbers in each sample set that are the same.

Comment: `==` is commutative. The order in which you place the operands is irrelevant; `a == b` is the same as `b == a`.

Comment: Makoto sorry I'm really tired. 4-4-5-5 would be 2.

Comment: numRepeat(7, 2, 2, 7); but there is no function numRepeat. :)

Comment: What would 4-4-4-5-5 be?  Would that be 2, also?

Comment: what are the constraints on the arguments?  All possible integers?  Non-negative?  Less than 10 (this is important since "11" is either a positive repeat or a single number)?

Comment: I'd have two sets.  Add the numbers into the first set.  If it's already there, try to add them into the second set instead.  Return the size of the second set.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this problem is to use a "map". A map will help you keep the number itself (called the "key" to the map), and the count (called the "value". Take a look at this [web page](http://www.stanford.edu/group/coursework/docsTech/jgl/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashMapExamples.html) to see how you can use maps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numRepeat(7, 2, 2, 7);
    }

    public static void numRepeat(int... nums) {

        Set<Integer> m = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int num : nums) {
            m.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of repeated digits is " + (nums.length - m.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `java.util.Set` instead.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux:  Why a Set?  What would that gain you except a list of non-duplicates?  That doesn't tell you what duplicates were in the list prior.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Previous commenter mentioned map so I used map :)

Comment: @Makoto "That doesn't tell you what duplicates were in the list prior" This was not required

Comment: @Makoto: Because the number of duplicates can be put in relation to the total amount of numbers and the amount of unique numbers: `#dup = #total - #unique`.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux:  I have input of `3-3-3-2-2`.  My uniques are 2.  My total is 5.  5 - 2 != 2.

Comment: Hey, Nikoloz... I don't know if this is too much to ask, but could you maybe write a few comments to it?? I've never seen anyone using "..." or ":" before... and how come you don't have to define num or nums??

Comment: for "..." you can read this: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html

Comment: for ":" you can read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

The most direct approach to this problem is a `Map` from int to int.

Why a map?

- They don't allow for duplicates.
- They allow you to conveniently retrieve information about a particular number in your collection.

Sample code to follow.  I'm assuming your information is coming from `numRepeat`, which takes an int varargs parameter.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> seenValues = new HashMap<>();

for(int val : parsedResults) {
    if(seenValues.containsKey(val)) {
        seenValues.put(val, seenValues.get(val) + 1);
    } else {
        seenValues.put(val, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (a == b || a == c || a == d) 
I think this should be there instead of
if (a == b || b == c || c == d)